# two windows installs, no communication between them?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have a PC built for gaming and an old macbook. The PC works great, nice specs, has an 250gb SSD and 2tb HDD. The macbook is only used for internet and daily use.

The issue is: I got a new job that demands I use a clean windows install and their provided softwares. All (even windows) will be bought by the company. There's no mac equivalent and my macbook probably would have problems running the softwares.

I thought about making a new partition in the PC, installing windows with their key and, finally, their softwares. The issue is: I don't want this partition to be "communicable". While in partition A (games), I don't want to see or influence partition B (work), and vice-versa.

A problem: I'm reckless with my PC. I install things without much safety, probably I get a few viruses before wiping it clean (which I do every two months) and only use it for gaming — no social media logged in, no personal information other than my steam acc logged. I'm much more cautious with my macbook, as I log on stuff there.

Three questions:

Is partitioning this way — without communication — possible?

If so, how?

Is it SAFE (most important)? If, let's say, I get a malicious software in partition A, will it be able to infect partition B?

PLAN B: Let's say all this isn't possible.

Is there a way to get a fresh SSD, install everything, boot it, and make it "no communication" with my games SSD/HDD without physically disconnecting them?

(VM is an option, but I fear keyloggers can get all my typed data if a virus is present)

Thanks a lot.

PS: yes, I know this is a stupid request being made by this company, but I'm ok with it.

Comment: The only way to avoid your careless actions from infecting the other partition would be use a removable hdd and swap the two HDDS.  Perhaps you should stop infecting your machine?  I have had the same installation, that isn't infected with malicious software, for over 10 years.

Comment: @Ramhound of course not infecting it would be a good (if not the **best** practice), but at the moment this is my "anything goes" computer. Swap HDDs is a viable (but not perfect) solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't guarantee that while booted into one partition, the other is inaccessible.  After all, Windows itself includes tools for adjusting partitions other than the one you booted with, so malware too could damage that partition.  Maybe no *subtle* damage like installing a rootkit or a bot, maybe just erasing the whole partition.

Similarly, if you disable access to a plugged-in external disk *from within Windows,* then malware could override that.  External disks with a physical write-protect switch have become extremely rare in recent years, probably because unplugging a USB cable is sufficient for most users.  Maybe you could enable/disable from the BIOS, but that's probably even more hassle than tweaking a cable.

The one thing you might try, if you know how to solder, would be to insert a 4PST switch into a USB extension cable.  That effectively unplugs what's at the other end, without adjusting any cables.

Comment: At a bare minimum a dpst, you only need to cut off the data lines to secure it.